# how to stop ssrs report url asking for cedentials

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

I deployed reports on test server.i am using ssrs 2008 r2.
testers and developers are on same domain called 'ASDF' and testreport server is on 'HIJL' domain.
when I try to access ' htt://testservername/reports ' from my dev or test machine it is asking for credentials 
If i put my windows login ,this isn't accepted.but if i enter HIJL\admin and password it accepts and showing reports.

I try to give permissions for 'ASDF' users but i am getting 'rsUnknownUserName' message.

how can i stop report manager asking the credential while opening it?

thanks

Comment: The easiest way to do this and could be acceptable in a test environment is to add a "ReportAdmin" and "ReportUser" windows user account the server(s). Then in SSRS give control to the local user. You should be able to login using the local account.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply.can you please explain  how to add add a "ReportAdmin" and "ReportUser" windows user account the server(s)?

Answer (score 0):

You configure a windows user account and give that account authorization to specific resources.

1. **Create a standard windows user on the SSRS server.**
2. **Open SSRS and select "site settings".**

[image]

3. **Select the "Security Tab"**

[image]

**4. Give the windows account specified in step 1 access by tying in the account name and selecting the roles to grant.**

[image]

**5. Navigate to the SSRS home screen and select the "Folder Settings" tab.**
[image]

**6. Select the "New Role Assignment Tab" on the security page of "Folder Settings" and add the user(s) you specified in step 4.** *NOTE: This will give ReportUser access to all reports deployed.*

[image]

This should give you easy access to deploy and access reports in a test environment.

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed explanation and your time. 
currently i am using 'HIJL\admin' windows user account for deploying reports.this account is like your ReportAdmin Account.
my problem is report manager keep asking for the credential while opening it in test or dev environment.
if i pass the 'HIJL\admin' credentials,it works fine.but i want to stop  report manager asking for credentials in test or dev environment.

pls help.

Comment: Then you need to specify a domain/username that maps to an admin account on the ssrs server. If windows authentication is being used for the ssrs manager site then you will always be required to supply network credentials. The only way around the security is to allow anonymous access or use custom security :(

Answer (score 0):

Can a trust be set up between the domains so that the ASDF users may be authenticated on the HIJL domain?

If not, like lrb said, your options then become anonymous access, or a custom security implementation.